# jQuery Mobile: Add url to collapsible content header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am a JQM newbie and need to put a linked image in the collapsible content header so that when it is clicked the user will be able to access the associated href.  I also need to be able to get the header to expand and collapse as needed.  Here is my code so far

```
<h3><em><?=$agent_row['prefix'] . ' ' . $agent_row['first'] . ' ' . $agent_row['last'] . ' ' . $agent_row['suffix']?>
    <a class="vcard" id="vcard" href="http://vcard.parascript.com/<?=$agent_row['first']?>_<?=$agent_row['last']?>.vcf"><img src="images/vcard.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" /></a>
    <a id="email" href="mailto:<?=$agent_row['email']?>"><img src="images/mail.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" /></a>
    <a id="mobilephone" href="tel://<?=$agent_row['cell']?>"><img src="images/mobile_phone.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" /></a>
</em></h3>
```

I appreciate any suggestions provided.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible.html

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/tJyeQ/

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div data-role="page"  id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>page1</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <h3><em>First Last</em></h3>
                <a class="vcard" id="vcard" href="http://vcard.parascript.com/first_last.vcf">
                    <img src="images/vcard.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" />
                </a>
                <a id="email" href="mailto:f.last@example.com"><img src="images/mail.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" />Email</a>
                <a id="mobilephone" href="tel://4155551212"><img src="images/mobile_phone.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" />Phone</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, but what I am looking to do is make the buttons in the collapsible header clickable.  Right now the header gets the focus regardless of where it is clicked.  What I am trying to do is allow focus to be assigned to images placed to the right of the <h3> element.

Comment: There is no way to do that with the collapsible header. I would suggest you use either [Layout Grids](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-grids.html) or [NavBars](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html). I can create an example if you want.

Comment: An example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough example using Layout Grids: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/tJyeQ/6/

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div data-role="page"  id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>page1</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-grid-c ui-btn ui-bar-c ui-corner-all">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus ui-icon-shadow"> </span>
                        <span class="ui-btn-text">First Last</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <a class="vcard" id="vcard" href="http://vcard.parascript.com/first_last.vcf">
                        <img src="images/vcard.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" />
                        vcard
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <a id="email" href="mailto:f.last@example.com">
                        <img src="images/mail.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" />
                        Email
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">
                    <a id="mobilephone" href="tel://4155551212">
                        <img src="images/mobile_phone.png" style="vertical-align:middle;width:30px;" />
                        Phone
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /grid-c -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This allows you to set a unique focus or button for each image and you could have the Name Show/Hide other content like a collapsible block, with just a little extra code.